# Why clojure filter evaluates first 32 elements of seq?

Tags: clojure

I'm playing with Clojure's lazy sequences and I have interesting observation. When I execute following code:

```
(first (filter (fn [x] (do (println x) (= x 2))) (range 1000)))
```

I got output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
=> 2
```

So, it seems that pred was called against first 32 elements of seq. Two questions occurs: why 32, and why pred was executed at all after second element?

Comment: Also see the blog post http://blog.fogus.me/2010/01/22/de-chunkifying-sequences-in-clojure/

Comment: ...this is also duplicative of [map not quite lazy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39957310/map-not-quite-lazy)

Comment: Yes, that answers my question, thank you. Anyway, thats a pity that such behavior is a default...

Comment: Performing well by default is important, and in most cases, chunking is a substantial net gain. It *wasn't* a default in Clojure 1.0, and when chunking was introduced in 1.1, it was widely considered a win by people actually using the language at the time.

Comment: ...keep in mind that one of the goals of writing good software in a functional language is that side effects should be contained and explicit -- so if you have a sequence that actually changes something in the outside world as it's realized, that's typically an indication of bad design. (By contrast, if you're running really expensive operations where chunking costs more than it saves, that's a different kind of corner case -- see links above).

Comment: Being intuitive is important too ;)

Comment: And yes, in my case I have expensive operation (http call) so I have to get rid of chunking

Comment: In the last seven years writing clojure full time, i think i've needed to de-chunk to avoid side effects only once or twice, so it does come up from time to time.